# Meaning of “arg min”

Tags: algorithms, terminology

Would someone be so kind to explain this to me:

$$\pi_nk=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}1&\textrm{if }k=\arg\min_j\left\Vert\mathbf x_n-\mu_j\right\Vert^2\\0&\textrm{otherwise}\end{array}\right..$$

Especially the $\arg\min$ part.

(It's from the $k$-means algorithm.)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Define $\arg\min_x f(x)$ as the set of values of $x$ for which the minimum of $f(x)$ is attained, so it is the set of values where the function attains the minimum. Thus, $\arg\min_x f(x)$ is a subset of the domain of $f(x)$.

For your example:
$x_n$ is known and depends on $\pi_{nk}$; $k$ equals to the value of $j$ such that $\begin{Vmatrix}
x_n-\mu_j
\end{Vmatrix}^2$ attains a minimum among all values of $\mu_j$ and given $x_n$.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: If you define arg min $f$ as *the set of values where the function attains its minimum*, then one should write $x\in $arg min $f$  whereas $x=$ arg min $f$ is not what most authors intend to say.

Answer (score 55):

$\arg \min$ (or $\arg \max$) return the input(s) for which the output is minimum (or maximum).

For example:

The graph illustrates the function $f(x)=2 \sin(x-0.5)+\cos(x)^2$.

The global minimum of $f(x)$ is $\min(f(x)) \approx -2$, while $\arg \min f(x)  \approx 4.9$.

[image]

Comment: The arrow is approximately pointing to the point: (4.9, -2)

Answer (score 18):

$\operatorname{argmin}(f(x))$ simply returns the value of $x$ which minimizes $f(x)$ over the set of candidates for $x$ as opposed to the minimum value itself.  This arises, of course, in all kinds of statistical estimates of parameters when building models (like the LS situation alluded to in your example).

Comment: Practical! yes it means argument that returns least not the least passed argument!