# Notation: what is "arg min"

Tags: optimization, notation

Let $A,B,X,Y$ be $4$ sets.
Let $f:X\to A$ and $g:Y\to B$ be a pair of functions. What is the common definition of the expression $\arg\min\{f(x),g(y)\}$?

---

As noted by the comment, $\text{argmin} f(x)$ is the $x$ that gives smallest $f$. But what happens when $\text{argmin}$ takes two function, what does say?

Comment: $\argmin f(x)$ is the set of values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ attains its minimum.

Comment: maybe dup?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227626/explanation-on-arg-min

Comment: There is an [explanation on arg min](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227626/explanation-on-arg-min) in our archives. The answer may be useful to you. What is the language? Just curious. That would indicate how to use the function.

Comment: @J.W.Perry, this notation is used in a research paper in optimization, and it is in english.

Comment: I see. It is a mathematical notation and not a programming language snippet. That clarifies things.

Comment: I don't think that's a standard notation; there's no obvious way to take the arg min of a *set* (since sets don't have arguments). Can you figure out what it might mean from context? Does the author explain their notation?

Comment: My best guess is that you're meant to evaluate over all values of $f(x)$ and $g(y)$, then take the $x$ or $y$ value that gives the smallest result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation on arg min](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227626/explanation-on-arg-min)